# Which versions of Visual Studio IDEs are supported with TFS 2017 & TFS 2018?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Without using GDR packages, which version of VS are compatible for working with TFS 2017 & TFS 2018.

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements Go to the very bottom of this page its explained there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We define three levels of client support for different versions of
>   Visual Studio and Team Explorer. **Only the latest version has "full"
>   compatibility with the latest Team Foundation Server**, because this
>   will be the only client that contains components that can interface
>   with new features for that release, and will also be the only client
>   from which you can perform certain administrative tasks such as
>   creating new team projects. Previous versions will have varying levels
>   of support below that, depending on how old they are.

[image]

Source Link: **[Client compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements)**. For TFS2018 should be the same as TFS2017&VS without special statement. ***Note:*** TFS 2018 discontinues support for the Xaml build system.